# xcode UICollectionView Cell autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collectionview that is full width of the screen, but I want the collectionview and the collectionview cell to adjust size according to the iPhone screen.

One cell takes up the collectionview and scrolls across.

So I want the cell and collectionview to be 320 x 125 for iPhone 4, 4s, 5, and 5s;
375 x 146 for iPhone 6 and 414 x 162 for iPhone 6 Plus.

It wasn't possible to use autolayout on the cell but I was able to for the collectionview.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could implement the delegate method for the cell size

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

You can return there the size you want.

What I did not really understand from your question was if the collection view already has the size you want. If so, in the delegate method you could do something like:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.collectionView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.collectionView.frame));
}
```

With this the cells should have the right size.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is the way to go, but is sooo annoying that there ain't a way to do this by constraints, especially since you want to have an idea of what you are doing!

Answer (score 0):

While defining frame of `UICollectionView` or `UICollectionViewCell`, define `width` frame value as `self.view.frame.size.width`.

It will automatically pick the full width which you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help! I put in this post - How to scale cells dynamically and proportionally depending on device screen!!!

[UICollectionView cells not horizontal after rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28088236/uicollectionview-cells-not-horizontal-after-rotation/28204705#28204705)