# iOS: UICollectionViewCell auto adjust size according to screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to create 10 cells in the collection view(same size as the screen). When I run my app in iphone5s simulator, the view contains exactly 5 cells. But when I switch to iphone6p simulator, the view contains more than 5 cells. How should I adjust the cell size so that the number of cells in screen are consistent across different screen sizes?

Comment: You don't need to adjust cell size.Just the collection view according to the iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 size.

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28088236/uicollectionview-cells-not-horizontal-after-rotation/28204705#28204705

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   int numberOfCellInRow = 3;
   CGFloat cellWidth =  [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/numberOfCellInRow;
   return CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellWidth);
}
```

Comment: set your collectionView width programmatically change with screen width.

Comment: if you have space between cell, consider it in your cell width calculation.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


return CGSizeMake([(NSString*)[[tagArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"tag"] sizeWithAttributes:NULL].width+10, 40);

}
```